# Dynamically added script section - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, amcharts

I am creating a page with multiple charts (using AmCharts), grids etc. Each chart has is own view. I noticed that when I try to link amcharts.js on each view, charts are not drawn when there are more than two charts on this page. I decided to put this link in the main page, common for all charts and they work fine, but now I cant see them by just calling action with an url. I tried to link them dynamically, like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
if ($("#amchartsLib").length == 0) {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "/Scripts/amcharts/amcharts.js";
script.id = "amchartsLib";
document.body.appendChild(script);
DrawChart();
```

Unfortunately - when firebug hits the line when I instantiate charts (new AmCharts.AmPieChart();) I get ReferenceError: Amcharts is not defined. What am I doing wrong? I can see that amcharts.js file has been properly added to the HTML document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you may have to wait till the script file is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#amchartsLib").length == 0) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/Scripts/amcharts/amcharts.js";
        script.id = "amchartsLib";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = function () {
            DrawChart();
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would call the script reference in your `_Layout.cshtml` file (assuming that's what you're using), and then use `Sections` to render the other script tags.  Something like this:

**Layout - head (abbreviated)**

```
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/amcharts/amcharts.js")"></script>
</head>
```

**Layout - bottom**

```
@RenderSection("BottomScripts", false) // false = section not required
```

**View (individual)**

```
@section BottomScripts
{
   // your chart script here
}
```